# jQuery Masonry infinite scroll and picture overlap problems with my tumblr theme

Tags: jquery-masonry

I am new in programming(javascript) but I've done quite a research the past few days in order to make my tumblr theme work correctly. I know my question is common but as it seems I don't have enough knowledge to integrate correctly parts of code that were given in many similar examples.

[My theme](http://freetexthost.com/zsw1nr3uii) is supposed to override the "15 posts per page" limitation of tumblr and with an "endless scroll" option it should put all my posts (all of them pictures) in one endless page. Well, It doesn't. With a little help from [here](http://codysherman.com/tools/infinite-scrolling), I managed to wrap my {block:Posts} with the  and with a couple of random changes in the masonry() call I ended up with [this](http://twoiscompany-eu.tumblr.com/)

As you can see my pictures are not overlapping (at last!) but after the 15 first posts it looks like a new page is created and the last pictures are not correctly aligned.

my jQuery masonry code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function () {
$('.autopagerize_page_element').masonry(),
$('.autopagerize_page_element').infinitescroll({
navSelector : "div.navigation",
// selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : "div.navigation a#nextPage",
// selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : ".autopagerize_page_element",
// selector for all items you'll retrieve
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 12000,
loadingImg : "http://b.imagehost.org/0548/Untitled-2.png",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function() { $('.autopagerize_page_element').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); }
);
});
</script>
```

I know, its a mess...
Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Have figured out the bug???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to work with tumblr, but I can what is happening:

[Line 110:](http://static.tumblr.com/thpaaos/lLwkowcqm/jquery.masonry.js)

This script is creating a wrapper div around the entries each time you call to masonry, because of the script, each load looks like a new page, I think you can simply remove it.

Some tips:
You don't have to wait $(windows).load to execute masonry, change it by $(function()

To avoid image overlapping use appened masonry method and imagesLoad: [Refer this](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html)

I see you're using masonry 1.0.1, be sure you're using masonry last version (2.1.06)

Example code:

```
$(function() {
    //$('.autopagerize_page_element').masonry();
    var $container = $('.autopagerize_page_element');
    //wait until images are loaded
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({itemSelector: '.entry'});
    });
$('.autopagerize_page_element').infinitescroll({
navSelector : "div.navigation",
// selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : "div.navigation a#nextPage",
// selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : ".entry",
// selector for all items you'll retrieve
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 12000,
loadingImg : "http://b.imagehost.org/0548/Untitled-2.png",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
},
// call masonry as a callback.
//function() { $('.autopagerize_page_element').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); }
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
    }
);
});
```

and be sure to remove the last script in this header block:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/imovwvl/dJWl20ley/jqueryformasonry.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script> <!-- last masonry version -->
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/df28qmy/SHUlh3i7s/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>
<!--<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/thpaaos/lLwkowcqm/jquery.masonry.js"></script>-->
```

Hope it helps